# Seek and you shall Scan... on partitioned tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, partitioning, query-performance

I've read these articles in PCMag by [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/author/itzik-ben-gan):

[Seek and You Shall Scan Part I: When the Optimizer Doesn't Optimize](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/seek-and-you-shall-scan-part-i-when-optimizer-doesnt-optimize)
[Seek and You Shall Scan Part II: Ascending Keys](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/seek-and-you-shall-scan-part-ii-ascending-keys)

I’m currently having a "Grouped Max" problem with all of our partitioned tables.
We use [the trick](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/max-and-min-aggregates-against-partitioned-tables) Itzik Ben-Gan provided for getting a max(ID), but sometimes it just doesn’t run:

```
DECLARE @MaxIDPartitionTable BIGINT
SELECT  @MaxIDPartitionTable = ISNULL(MAX(IDPartitionedTable), 0)
FROM    ( SELECT    *
          FROM      ( SELECT    partition_number PartitionNumber
                      FROM      sys.partitions
                      WHERE     object_id = OBJECT_ID('fct.MyTable')
                                AND index_id = 1
                    ) T1
                    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    ISNULL(MAX(UpdatedID), 0) AS IDPartitionedTable
                                  FROM      fct.MyTable s
                                  WHERE     $PARTITION.PF_MyTable(s.PCTimeStamp) = PartitionNumber
                                            AND UpdatedID <= @IDColumnThresholdValue
                                ) AS o
        ) AS T2;
SELECT @MaxIDPartitionTable
```

I get this plan

[image]

But after 45 minutes, look at the reads

```
reads          writes   physical_reads
12,949,127        2       12,992,610
```

that I get out of `sp_whoisactive`.

Normally it runs quite quickly, but not today.

Edit:
table structure with partitions:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [MonthlySmallDateTime](SmallDateTime) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'2000-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2000-02-01T00:00:00.000' /* and many more */)
go
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_FctContractualAvailability AS PARTITION [MonthlySmallDateTime] TO ([Standard], [Standard])
GO
CREATE TABLE fct.MyTable(
    MyTableID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [DT1TurbineID] INT NOT NULL,
    [PCTimeStamp] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    Filler CHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    UpdatedID BIGINT NULL,
    UpdatedDate DATETIME NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DT1TurbineID] ASC,
    [PCTimeStamp] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW) ON [PS_FctContractualAvailability]([PCTimeStamp])
) ON [PS_FctContractualAvailability]([PCTimeStamp])

GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UpdatedID_PCTimeStamp] ON [fct].MyTable
(
    [UpdatedID] ASC,
    [PCTimeStamp] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [UpdatedDate]) 
WHERE ([UpdatedID] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW) ON [PS_FctContractualAvailability]([PCTimeStamp])
GO
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The basic issue is that the Index Seek is not followed by a Top operator. This is an optimization that is usually introduced when the seek returns rows in the correct order for a `MIN\MAX` aggregate.

This optimization exploits the fact that the min/max row is the first one in ascending or descending order. It may also be that the optimizer cannot apply this optimization to partitioned tables; I forget.

Anyway, the point is that without this transformation, the execution plan ends up processing every row that qualifies `S.UpdatedID <= @IDColumnThresholdValue` per partition, rather than the desired one row per partition.

You have not provided table, index, or partitioning definitions in the question so I can't be much more specific. You should check that your index would support such a transformation. More or less equivalently, you could also express the `MAX` as a `TOP (1) ... ORDER BY UpdatedID DESC`.

If this results in a Sort (including a [TopN Sort](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/sql-plan/internals-of-the-seven-sql-server-sorts-part-1)), you know your index is not helpful. For example:

```
SELECT
    @MaxIDPartitionTable = ISNULL(MAX(T2.IDPartitionedTable), 0)
FROM    
( 
    SELECT
        O.IDPartitionedTable
    FROM      
    ( 
        SELECT
            P.partition_number AS PartitionNumber
        FROM sys.partitions AS P
        WHERE 
            P.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'fct.MyTable', N'U')
            AND P.index_id = 1
    ) AS T1
    CROSS APPLY 
    (    
        SELECT TOP (1) 
            S.UpdatedID AS IDPartitionedTable
        FROM fct.MyTable AS S
        WHERE
            $PARTITION.PF_MyTable(S.PCTimeStamp) = T1.PartitionNumber
            AND S.UpdatedID <= @IDColumnThresholdValue
        ORDER BY
            S.UpdatedID DESC
    ) AS O
) AS T2;
```

The plan shape this should produce is:

[image: Desired plan shape]

Notice the Top below the Index Seek. This limits the processing to one row per partition.

Or, using a temporary table to hold partition numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE #Partitions
(
    partition_number integer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

INSERT #Partitions
    (partition_number)
SELECT
    P.partition_number AS PartitionNumber
FROM sys.partitions AS P
WHERE 
    P.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'fct.MyTable', N'U')
    AND P.index_id = 1;

SELECT
    @MaxIDPartitionTable = ISNULL(MAX(T2.UpdatedID), 0)
FROM #Partitions AS P
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP (1) 
        S.UpdatedID
    FROM fct.MyTable AS S
    WHERE
        $PARTITION.PF_MyTable(S.PCTimeStamp) = P.partition_number
        AND S.UpdatedID <= @IDColumnThresholdValue
    ORDER BY
        S.UpdatedID DESC
) AS T2;

DROP TABLE #Partitions;
```

Side note: accessing a system table in your query prevents parallelism. If this is important, consider materializing the partition numbers in a temporary table, then `APPLY` from that. Parallelism is not normally helpful in this pattern (with correct indexing) but it would be remiss of me not to mention it.

Side note 2: There is an [active Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/240968) requesting built-in support for `MIN\MAX` aggregates and Top on partitioned objects.